# как получить одно значение из таблицы в entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Мне нужно получить только одно значение из таблицы, делаю его так:

```
public DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
public ObservableCollection<Users> GetUsers
{
   get { return db.Users.Local; }
}
public WindowViewModel(Label userName)
{
    var us = GetUsers.Where(u => u.Id == 1) as Users;
    userName.Content = us.Name.ToString();
}
```

Но так не получается выдает ошибку: Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: Как вы думаете, что означает свойство Local?

Comment: И как вы приводите коллекцию к элементу?

Comment: Вместо `Where` используйте `Single`/`SingleOrDefault`

Comment: и вот эта часть мне кажется очень сомнительной `ObservableCollection<Users> GetUsers`

Comment: Если бы я знал тогда я не спросил, я только что начал программировать уже второй день. Посоветуйте мне пожалуйста поподробнее

Comment: не совсем понятно что нужно посоветовать. Есть возможность описать задачу более подробно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ:

```
//возвращает перечисление пользователей, фильтрованных данным выражением
Public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
{
    return db.Users.Where(expression);
}
// возвращает первое вхождение пользователя, отфильтрованного данным выражением
Public User GetUser(Expression<Func<User, bool>> expression)
{
    return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(expression);
}

public WindowViewModel(Label userName)
{
    var us = GetUser(u => u.Id == 1);
    userName.Content = us.Name.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Здорово, поздравляю!

Comment: Спасибо очень рад